# Android DataBinding item position in a recyclerView

Tags: android, data-binding, kotlin

I have a Fragment with a ViewModel (so Mvvm) and in the xml I have 2 RecyclerView with both having their own Adapter using the same itemList because I want to see the same data in 2 different layout.

Before switching to Mvvm, I could reference the adapter and the recyclerView and could reach "getChildAdapterPosition"

But right now this is quite impossible it seem. I made some custom BindingAdapter to bind my Adapter, a CustomPageSnaperHelper and a scrollListener. but now I can't seem to be able to sync the 2 to show the same item even if i scroll the bottom one or the top one.

Gonna post some code snippet, but not sure which one would help more:

```
@JvmStatic @BindingAdapter("adapter")
fun <T : RecyclerView.ViewHolder> setRvAdapter(rv: RecyclerView, adapter: RecyclerView.Adapter<T>?) {
    if(adapter != null) rv.adapter = adapter
}

@JvmStatic @BindingAdapter("pageSnapper")
fun setPageSnapper(rv: RecyclerView, cs: CustomSnapHelper?){
    cs?.attachToRecyclerView(rv)
}

@JvmStatic @BindingAdapter("rvScrollListener")
fun setRvScrollListener(rv: RecyclerView, sl: RecyclerView.OnScrollListener?){
    if (sl == null) return
    rv.addOnScrollListener(sl)
}
```

Xml:

```
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        adapter="@{vm.OCardAdapter}"
        pageSnapper="@{vm.OCardPageSnaper}"
        rvScrollListener="@{vm.OCardScrollListener}"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/top_tabs"
        tools:listItem="@layout/card_layout" />

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        adapter="@{vm.OCarouselAdapter}"
        pageSnapper="@{vm.OCarouselPageSnaper}"
        rvScrollListener="@{vm.OCarouselScrollListener}"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:background="@color/colorWhite"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        tools:listItem="@layout/carousel_layout"/>
```

To be fair I could paste in more of my code, but I don't think it could help more ish.

```
val scrollListenerCard = object: RecyclerView.OnScrollListener(){
    var mScrolled = false
    override fun onScrolled(recyclerView: RecyclerView, dx: Int, dy: Int) {
        super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy)
    }

    override fun onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView: RecyclerView, newState: Int) {
        super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could create

```
@InverseBindingAdapter(attribute = "currentPosition")
public static int getCurrentPosition(final RecyclerView rv) {
return ((LinearLayoutManager) rv.getLayoutManager()).findFirstVisibleItemPosition();
}

@BindingAdapter(value = "currentPositionAttributeChanged")
public static void setListener(final RecyclerView rv, final InverseBindingListener l) {
final int prevPos = ((LinearLayoutManager)rv.getLayoutManager()).findFirstVisibleItemPosition();

        rv.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
                super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
                if (dy == 0) {
                    return;
                }

                int newPosition = linearLayoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();
                if (previousPosition != newPosition) {
                    l.onChange();
                }
            }
        }); 
}

@BindingAdapter("currentPosition")
public void setCurrentPosition(final RecyclerView rv, final int pos) {
// no need to do anything here - setter required by databinding
}
```

These would give you access to the positions, or you can set these listeners by accessing bindings inside your fragment/activity and update your viewModel from there.

Comment: Thanks for this! Works nicely with a few adjustments. I made a new answer in kotlin based on this below.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that I understand your problem well but if I had to create two rw-s that are always scrolled to the same position with databindig, than I would give adapter A to scroll listener B as a constructor parameter (and inversely too) and this way I would call the adapter's scrollTo() method when the listener fires.

```
class MyScrollListener(private val recyclerView: RecyclerView): RecyclerView.OnScrollListener(){
        var mScrolled = false
        override fun onScrolled(recyclerView: RecyclerView, dx: Int, dy: Int) {
            super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy)
        }
        override fun onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView: RecyclerView, newState: Int) {
            super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState)
            this.recyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(newState)
        }

    }

    val scrollListenerCard = MyScrollListener(recyclerView)
```

Comment: My ScrollListener are object i've built. I've added them at the end of the question, im really sorry but i don't know how to add the adapter as a constructor to them, could you help me with that ?

Comment: Updated my original answer. I was wrong you need the rw instead of the adapter but the concept is the same.

Answer (score 0):

Based on Mirza's answer above, I came up with this in kotlin, which works nicely:

```
    @JvmStatic
    @InverseBindingAdapter(attribute = "currentPosition", event = "currentPositionAttributeChanged")
    fun getCurrentPosition(rv: RecyclerView): Int {
        return (rv.layoutManager as LinearLayoutManager).findFirstVisibleItemPosition()
    }

    @JvmStatic
    @BindingAdapter(value = ["currentPositionAttributeChanged"])
    fun setListener(rv: RecyclerView, l: InverseBindingListener) {
        val layoutManager = (rv.layoutManager as LinearLayoutManager?)!!
        var prevPos = layoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition()
        rv.addOnScrollListener(object : RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
            override fun onScrolled(recyclerView: RecyclerView, dx: Int, dy: Int) {
                super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy)
                if (dy == 0) {
                    return
                }
                val newPos = layoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition()
                if (prevPos != newPos) {
                    prevPos = newPos
                    l.onChange()
                }
            }
        })
    }

    @JvmStatic
    @BindingAdapter("currentPosition")
    fun setCurrentPosition(rv: RecyclerView, pos: Int) {
        (rv.layoutManager as LinearLayoutManager).scrollToPosition(pos)
    }
```

I use it like this:

ViewModel has:

`val currentPos = MutableLiveData<Int>()`

And the layout has:

```
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        currentPosition="@={viewModel.currentPos}"
        app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager">
```